# JavaScript on click change width by class

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

If I click a button I can assign it a function like bellow

```
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250";
```

This works fine, however I wish do give it a different width for different screen sizes so I was going to set the width in a class so that i can use a css media query. 
instead of `.style.width = "250";`how can I tell it to take the values of a CSS class instead ?>

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: sounds like you are asking about media queries

Comment: yep, i will be using a media query in my css

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, CSS names cannot start with digits, [per the W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters). Your edited post removes the need for this comment but it's worth noting.

To manipulate classes via JavaScript, either use `className` (as in `myElement.className = 'some-class'`) or the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) interface. However, you specifically mentioned "different screen sizes" and this is a prime candidate for [responsive CSS queries using the `@media` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width).

With all that being said:

**JavaScript example**

```
// CSS
#mySidenav {
     width: 1000px;
}

#mySidenav.responsive-class {
     width: 500px;
}

// JS

const mySidenav = document.querySelector('#mySidenav');

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
     if (window.innerWidth < 200) {
          mySidenav.classList.add('responsive-class');
     }
     else {
          mySidenav.classList.remove('responsive-class');
     }
});
```

**CSS example**

```
#mySidenav {
     width: 1000px;
}

@media query and (max-width: 200px) {
     #mySidenav {
          width: 500px;
     }
}
```

As you can see, the latter example is much simpler. Go with the CSS approach. A halo will appear over you.

Comment: based of your answer I have tried ` document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.add('popoutwidth');` this seems to do the job. however when i close the div (another function it dose not pop back out.)

Comment: @Beep Great. You'll need to provide a working code example (CodePen, JSFiddle) for the community to help you further. It's probably an issue with [CSS specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I used @Shenh's answer to work out a solution +1 Sheng.

Please see bellow I added new class and removed class

```
    function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.add('popoutwidth');
    }

   function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.remove('popoutwidth');
   }
```